# "can't evaluate field key in type interface" accessing Keys in Go template

Tags: go, go-templates

My template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>{{ .title }}</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/></head><body><p>New Id On My Website</p><table><tbody>{{/* key, val */}}{{ range .lead }}<tr><td><strong>{{ .key }}</strong></td><td>{{ .val }}</td></tr>{{ end }}</tbody></table></body></html>
```

This is my data.

```
 {
    "lead": {
          "MOBILE": "1212121212121"
      },
     "title" : "New ID"
    }
```

If I execute this template with the data, it gives the following error.

```
template: tmpl:1:222: executing "tmpl" at <.key>: can't evaluate field key in type interface {}
```

My code :

```
var tmplBytes bytes.Buffer
err = tmpl.Execute(&tmplBytes, vars)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Here vars is the JSON in the form of `map[string]interface{}`

[Reproducible example](https://play.golang.org/p/PHryO8IaOHc)

Comment: According to that json, it should be {{.data.title}}, not {{.title}}

Comment: correction. Fixing it. I am passing only the data part @BurakSerdar

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg added

Comment: As the error states, the value does not have the key `key`.  I think you intended to write `{{range $key, $value := .lead}}` and use the values `{{$key}}` and `{{$value}}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your range function is wrong. I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302520/iterating-through-map-in-template) and updated your code accordingly. It worked. Here is the [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/CJeM5Z7RVZn).

The only difference is , I updated your range template to:

```
<tbody>
{{ range $key,$value := .lead }}
<tr><td><strong>{{ $key }}</strong></td>
<td>{{ $value }}</td></tr>
{{ end }}
</tbody>
```